# parse a date to utc unixtime

Tags: python-2.7, python-dateutil

a commandline program i am writing accepts dates as arguments. i need to convert these to a utc unix timestamp for internal use within the program. so far i have the following test script, but its not working:

```
>>> import time
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> t = parser.parse("2009-01-10")
>>> print int(time.mktime(t.timetuple()))
1231507800
```

checking this on [unixtimestamp.com](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php):

> 1231507800
>
> Is equivalent to:
>
> 01/09/2009 @ 1:30pm (UTC)

however i want it back at midnight. i think my computer is using my local timezone, when i want to use utc at every stage.

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subtract the date from the epoch and call the [`timedelta.total_seconds`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method:

```
import datetime as DT
from dateutil import parser
datestring = "2009-01-10"
date = parser.parse(datestring)
epoch = DT.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
timestamp = (date - epoch).total_seconds()
print(timestamp)
```

prints

```
1231545600.0
```

Another alternative is to use [`calendar.timegm`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) and [`datetime.utctimetuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utctimetuple) since both of these functions interpret their argument as being in UTC,

```
import calendar
print(calendar.timegm(date.utctimetuple()))
# 1231545600
```

but note that `date.utctimetuple()` drops microseconds.

Comment: i guess this indicates that `parser.parse` was correct and it must have been `time.mktime` that was converting for my timezone instead of using utc.

Comment: Yes, `time.mktime` interprets its argument as a local timetuple. `calendar.timegm` interprets its argument as a UTC timetuple. You could use `calendar.timegm(t.utctimetuple())`, but `utctimetuple` drops microseconds, while the method above does not.